# поиск по названию модели из модели django

Tags: python, django, поиск

Есть модель заказов, куда падают новые заказы с информацией, фото1

[image: 1]

Часть инфы это модель кроссовок, иногда эти кроссовки нужно исправить, сейчас это сделано в виде TabularInline, фото2 и фото3, кроссовок много и листать этот выпадающий список очень долго, есть ли способ сделать поиск по вводу текста, как search_fields?

admin.py

```
class SuitItemInOderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SuitInOder
    extra = 0

class SuitOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SuitItemInOderInline]
    list_display = ('inst', 'created')
    list_filter = ('status',)


class Meta:
    model = OrderSuit
    

admin.site.register(OrderSuit, SuitOrderAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class SuitInOder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderSuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Заказ', related_name='ordered_item')
    item = models.ForeignKey(SuitItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Костюм', related_name='spb_item')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.order} | {self.item.model.id} --- {self.item}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        not_available = ['new', 'in_progress', 'completed']
        if self.order.status in not_available:
            self.item.in_stock = False
        else:
            self.item.in_stock = True
        self.item.save(force_update=True)
        super(SuitInOder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self):
        self.item.in_stock = True
        self.item.save(force_update=True)
        super(SuitInOder, self).delete()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Костюм в заказе'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Костюмы в заказе'

class OrderSuit(models.Model):
    NEW = 'new'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress'
    COMPLETED = 'completed'
    CANCELED = 'canceled'

    choises = (
        (NEW, 'Новый'),
        (IN_PROGRESS, 'В работе'),
        (COMPLETED, 'Выполнен'),
        (CANCELED, 'Отменен')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='Имя', blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    inst = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='Адресс')
    deliver_time = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, verbose_name='Время доставки')
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name='Комментарий')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choises, null=True, verbose_name='Статус заказа')
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Время заказа', editable=False, default=datetime.now()+timedelta(hours=3))


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created = datetime.now() +timedelta(hours=3) 
        if self.id:
            items = self.ordered_item.all()
            for item in items:
                item.save()

        super(OrderSuit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ костюма'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы костюмов'
```

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Пример поиска]
Нужно зарегистрировать новую модель, например SuitSearch, в которой аргумент search_fileds будет принимать в моем случае model__name, где model это ссылается на item.model, а name на item.model.name, item будет аргументом autocomplete_fields в SuitItemInOderInline

```
class SuitSearch(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ('model__name',)
    
   class Meta:
       model = SuitItem

admin.site.register(SuitItem, SuitSearch)        


class SuitItemInOderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SuitInOder
    autocomplete_fields = ('item',)
    extra = 0

class SuitOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SuitItemInOderInline]
    list_display = ('inst', 'created')
    list_filter = ('status',)


    class Meta:
        model = OrderSuit
        

admin.site.register(OrderSuit, SuitOrderAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно в admin.py добавить вашу модель и добавить ей атрибут search_fields = ('название атрибута')
потом в конце ее зарегестрировать
Например:

```
from .models import News #Импорт вашей модели


# Register your models here.

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_published')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('title', 'content') #!!!!! Вот тут
    list_editable = ('is_published',)
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'category')


admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin) #Регистрация вашей модели
```

Comment: Таким образом можно добавить окно поиска на "главную" страницу модели в админ панели. Мне нужно добавить окно поиска модели в модели

Comment: добавил код в свой вопрос